# How to grep 7 lines after match and replace text?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, grep

I'm trying grep  7 lines after match and replace a context in those 7 lines and save it in the same file.

For Example:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

i would like to replace the value of `MaxRequestsPerChild`  with `5000`.

I have tried with:

```
grep "IfModule prefork.c" httpd.conf -A7 | /bin/sed -nE "/\bMaxRequestsPerChild\b/ s/[0-9]+/50/"
```

But no luck.

Comment: why not just grep for the string you're looking for in the first place?

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit daft, but why not just change the line in an editor?

Comment: @imabug there are other modules having the same pattern.

Comment: @Kusalananda need to configure in 73 machines.

Comment: there is several problem here, first, you want to edit a file and you do not provide sed with a file name but with stdin. So sed will never work, I suggest you write a script that get line number with grep and then sed inline at the properline number. I will not help you make this logic a oneliner

Comment: @Kiwy Sounds good. let wait if anybody have better solution.

Comment: @nkmoxk You're administrating 73 machines. Are you thinking you would run this over SSH in a loop?  Have you considered Ansible?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes its in roadmap, but it would take time. I thought shell scripting would be a meantime solution.

Comment: Ansible Salt Stack Puppet chef, anything that helps industrialize stuff (though I prefer the two first solution to puppet and chef which are heavy and complex IMHO

Comment: is `MaxRequestsPerChild` always 6th line after the match or it could be different?

Comment: @Sundeep it has to be. but not sure thats why i'm not focusing on line numbers.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a title closer to your requirement, something like "change Apache's MaxRequestsPerChild value to 5000 in the prefork.c module"

Comment: @JeffSchaller not only for `MaxRequestsPerChild ` in need to do edit  all parameters. Thats why I put a generic title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SED solution.

```
sed '/<IfModule prefork.c>/,/MaxRequestsPerChild/s/MaxRequestsPerChild.*/MaxRequestsPerChild 5000/' apacheconf
```

It works by matching the Module name then replacing the next "MaxRequestsPerChild" line with the 5000 value. It will ignore the "MaxRequestsPerChild" of all other modules.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed (not sure if syntax/feature is okay for other versions)

To change within 6 lines after matching line:

```
sed -E '/IfModule prefork\.c/{N;N;N;N;N;N;s/(MaxRequestsPerChild +)[0-9]+/\15000/}'
```

here, `N` will add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space

If it is always 6th line:

```
sed -E '/IfModule prefork\.c/{n;n;n;n;n;n;s/[0-9]+/5000/}'
```

here `n` will replace the pattern space with the next line of input

Or, simpler syntax with relative addressing

```
sed -E '/IfModule prefork\.c/,+6 s/(MaxRequestsPerChild +)[0-9]+/\15000/'
```

Comment: Thanks, but not getting the result. Looks like problem with `[0-9]+`

Comment: @nkmoxk can you give details.. did you get an error? or something else happened? it works for me on GNU sed(you've tagged linux, so I'm assuming you have GNU sed)

Comment: its not replacing the value. if i remove `+` sign, it replaces only the first digit as expected.

Comment: did you use `sed -E` ? may be your version needs `sed -r`?

Answer (score 0):

You could put  **sed's** `range operator ,` to good use here in case you are indifferent to line numbers:

```
sed -e '
   /<IfModule prefork.c>/,\|</IfModule>|!b
   H;\|</IfModule>|!d;g;s/.//;
   s/\(\(\n\)MaxRequestsPerChild[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)[1-9][0-9]*\n/\15000\2/
' config-file
```

1. Store the range in the hold space.
2. When the range end is detected, retrieve the range from the hold area, and
3. Perform the desired substitution.
4. Lines not falling in the range are left to themselves and passed on to stdout.

Comment: `sed -e '
   /<IfModule prefork.c>/,\|</IfModule>|!b
   H;\|</IfModule>|!d;g;s/.//;
   s/\(\(\n\)MaxRequestsPerChild[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)[1-9][0-9]*\n/\15000\2/
' httpd.conf | head -n108 | tail -n1`
**MaxRequestsPerChild  5000**

Comment: Thanks, but its not substituting.

Comment: @nkmoxk You  cannot write the `sed` command in one line as you've shown. Give each line of sed code with it's own `-e` option.